# picturebox wont show up

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

**did that code and the picture just dont appear no eror no message just open the screen the board there but the picture not**

```
public static void Create(Button[,] board)
    {
        PictureBox[] BlackpawnsPictureboxes = new PictureBox[8];
        const int tileSize = 50;

        var newPictureBox = new PictureBox
        {
            Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
        };

        for (var m = 0; m < 8; m++)
        {

            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m] = newPictureBox;

            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Location = board[1, m].Location;

            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\USER\source\repos\chess\chess\piece\white\pown.jpg");

            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Visible = true;

            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not adding the new Controls to an existing parent container. Btw, load the Bitmap just once, assign it to a Property/Field. Maybe add it to the Project's Resources and load it from there (just once).

Comment: you need something like - `Panel.Children.Add(BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m]);`

Comment: two question about that first why panel its a picture box second what do you mean by children cause it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @Jimi can you explain  yourself dont really get what you said...

Comment: Controls need to be *parented* to a container. The *natural* container is the Form. All controls need to have a Form container. Most controls, when created, can also host other Controls. Use the [Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls) collection to add child Controls to an existing Control that acts as container. If you want to add your PictureBox Controls directly to the Form: `var pBox = New PictureBox(); this.Controls.Add(pBox);` or `pBox.Parent = this;`. Or add a Panel (or other container) to the Form, then `[Panel].Controls.Add(pBox);`

Comment: @jimi 
var pBox = new PictureBox();
                BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Controls.Add(pBox);
                pBox.Parent = BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m];

                Panel.pBox.Add(BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m]);

like that?

Comment: cause it gives me an eror "'panel' does not contain a definition for 'pBox'"

Comment: Did you add a Panel to your Form? If so, then `var pBox = new PictureBox(); [YourPanel].Controls.Add(pBox);` OR `var pBox = new PictureBox(); pBox.Parent = [YourPanel];`. The method you use depends on the context.

Comment: @Jimi your panel means BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m] in my code? (the picture boxes im trying to make apear)

Comment: Nope, that's just an array of Controls you're building. If you want to add your PictureBox Controls to a Panel, go to the Form Designer and drop in a Panel from the ToolBox.

Comment: @Jimi ok added a plane did that 
var pBox = new PictureBox();
                panel1.Controls.Add(pBox);
how do i continue now?

Comment: @yuval464:     Even better, you could just google a bit on how to make chess in c# and you can find complete video tutorials.

Comment: @DJ thank you but not looking for a full game just trying to make my game and challange myself for my project

Comment: @Jimi you helped me then here and I didn't understood that re-uploaded my current code can you try to reexplain that?